# Windows authentication application hosting on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication

I have a windows authentication application built on my local computer. And when run the application it is asking for login credentials. When i use them as follows everything works fine.(my computer is under ASD domain)

```
Username:  ASD\username
password : ******
```

After when i deploy the application onto server which has different domain, and for the same application and accessing it from my local computer, it is not working. Because that above user is not there on the server and it is under different domain.

But i want to get the current computer's domain instead of where the application has been hosted.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Windows Authentication only works when both computers are joined to the same domain.  is this ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes, it is built on ASP.NET platform..

Comment: yes, you'll need to have both computers on the domain.  See http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication

Comment: Any workaround for this? I am half way on building my application . Ohh I am in a critical situation then, we can't move users to the domain where server exists or vice versa.

Comment: you could query Active Directory on the other domain, but you'll still need an account to query with and it won't be integrated authentication.  In this case, you may be just as well off with Forms Authentication.

Comment: The server has to be able to talk to the domain the user is in, but they don't have to be the same domain.  @PeterRitchie's article only says it is recommended they are in the same domain.  That way you can have single-sign-on with the server.

Comment: Domain/forest trust could be an option. That way your server would recognize your clients accounts as valid.